# Xampp doesn't work on Mac X

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, localhost, localserver

So here is what happens when i run xampp by clicking on the manager-osx.

- I click on "manager-osx".
- Icon jumps in the dock as if it is starting the service.
- Asks for admin password. I enter the password.
- It accepts the password, and application keep jumping in the docs for 3-4 times.
- The app disappear from the dock.

The issue started after i have quit few processes from the activity monitor.
I am not sure what has affected xampp and can't remember what services i have stopped as there were many.

Solution applied so far:

- Restarted my MacBook Pro.
- Exit all other application and tried to run xampp.
- Made sure no other application is running on port 80.
- Removed xampp from applications and tried to reinstalled. Same issue with re-installation process, It asks for admin password and then nothing happens.
- search online for any help but nothing helpful found.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got any experience with XAMMP but MAMP works always fine for me. MAMP has everything I need in terms of functionality. 
I would recommend MAMP

Comment: I would go for MAMP straight away but I have very complex websites and applications in htdocs that can only be recovered if the server starts running. That is the reason why i must make it work.

Comment: Have you tried a port number above 1000? OS X blocks most of the ports below 1000

Answer (score 0):

If MAMP is not the best solution for you. You can install manualy 
APACHE + PHP + MYSQL (It's not so hard)

Just go step by step using tutorial like 
[This](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/)

Manual installation will give you much more controll on your enviroment.

And also you will have better output to attach it here if you can't find a problems.
Of course it's little bit longer than 3 clicks. But on all production servers you need to install environment manually. This knowledge you will use later much more times. You will better understand how all is works and how to find reason of bug.(error)

Comment: and i think the link you have provided with "THIS" is broken. Could you please update? thanks.

Comment: already updated! If something isn't clear please inform me in comment.